# In Spring MVC, what is the best way to keep track of a session attribute for use in all jsps?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session-variables

I have an **accountType** variable which is set when a user logs in to my web application.

On many of my jsps, I need to check the value for accountType so that I can show (or not show) various content accordingly.

At the moment I am setting the accountType for each model corresponding to the jsp which needs to check the accountType. In the JSP, I do a check as follows:

```
<c:if test = "${myModel.accountType == 'B 2 C'}" >
    ... show B 2 C content ...
</c:if>
```

Unfortunately, it is quite labour intensive to set accountType for each model that requires it. Is there a similar way to read a session variable in my jsps or do I have to use scriptlets when checking a session variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you add the accountType to the session using the attribute name "accountType", you can access it in the JSP using `${accountType}` or (to avoid scope clashes) `${sessionScope.accountType}`.

`${foobar}` looks for an attribute named foobar in the page, then in the request, then in the session, then in the application scope (servlet context).

Comment: Yes, you can use JSTL tags to access the values. That is quite simple.